# How to Play Background Music using MonoTouch While App Running

Tags: c#, ios5, xamarin.ios, background-music

What would be the easiest way to have a music file included in the App as looped background music while the app is running and the music pauses if the app is suspended and starts up again when the app is brought back to foreground.  Don't care about playing for the devices iTunes/Music catalog just one or more included music files within the App bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the easiest way, but there is some sample code in [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Audio/AudioPlay.cs) to play audio in your app.